# how do I write a Ruby scheduler that spawns and tracks separate timed workers?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

So I am trying to write this scheduler that spawns and manages multiple timed workers. The scheduler should be able to decide the lifespan of a worker/thread, spawn the worker, report when the worker is crashed, and kill the worker gracefully when it needs to.

How do I do this? Any advice, comments or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "So I am trying to write ..." - so what have you actually tried before posting this question?

Comment: Your attempts and problems faced will be appreciated by the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "worker" could mean any number of things, but it sounds like you might want something like [god](http://godrb.com)